# How do I implement admob rewarded ads into unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads, reward

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class GameAdvertising : MonoBehaviour {

    public RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;
    bool hasPlayed;

    void Start () {
        rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
    }

    public void playAd()
    {
        AdRequest rewardrequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build(); 
        rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(rewardrequest, "ca-app-pub-5920324855307233/4458481507");
        rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }
}
```

In my code above **I have tried** to implement the admob reward video ad into my game inside a method that is called from a  ui button press. The advertise did not appear on my phone when the method was called (It works on the demo script and banners etc. works. I have imported all SDks and other files successful). What did I do wrong here and how do i put it in properly. Also how do i check when the ad is finished so i can reward the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to OnAdRewarded Ad event with `RewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;`.

Just call `RequestRewardBasedVideo()` from the `Start` function to test this. This code below is from [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/games#rewarded_video_mediation) and I modified it a little bit.

```
private void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_AD_UNIT_HERE";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_AD_UNIT_HERE";
    #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);

    //Show Ad
    showAdd(rewardBasedVideo);
}

private void showAdd(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo)
{
    if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
    {
        //Subscribe to Ad event
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
        rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }
}
```

//This function is called when video ad has finished showing You can reward player here with the amount variable.

```
public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{
    string type = args.Type;
    double amount = args.Amount;
    //Reawrd User here
    print("User rewarded with: " + amount.ToString() + " " + type);
}
```

Comment: Also make sure to put your ID  **ca-app-pub-5920324855307233/4458481507** in `adUnitId`.

Comment: I was getting this error when I try to use same above code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6CFlS0aZDPiZUFnbG9paTZUVEU

Comment: @Siddharth Create a new question with your non working code for that and make sure to accept the answer you get if the answer solved your problem. Also provide a  link to where you downloaded the admob plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I using this plugin  https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob 
and code like this.

load video

```
   Admob.Instance().loadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
```

Shown at game over , check that the video is ready before showing it:

```
   if (Admob.Instance().isRewardedVideoReady()) {
     Admob.Instance().showRewardedVideo();
   }
```

handle ad event

```
Admob.Instance().videoEventHandler += onInterstitialEvent;
    void onInterstitialEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
    Debug.Log("handler onAdmobEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    if (eventName == AdmobEvent.onAdLoaded)
    {
        Admob.Instance().showRewardedVideo();
    }
}
```